# Login to website through CURL and client browser

Tags: php, curl

My current situation is the following.

I have a vbulletin forum on websitea.com

I log in using the vbulletin login form, on successful login i use a vbulletin plugin to access an api through curl on websiteb.com. This api sets session information to log in the user on websiteb.com

The problem I have is that now when i visit websiteb.com through the browser the user is not logged into the website.

Is there anyway to get this to work? Or should i approach this from another angle?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you saying that you use php and curl to log someone in.. then when that person opens a browser and hits the page they're not logged in?

Comment: Do these two domains have access to the same database server, do you have control over the secondary website code base?

Comment: @MikeB Yes i use PHP and CURL to log someone in from my vbulletin installation in a plugin hook location. Then the person who logged into vbulletin, should be able to visit websiteb.com and see that they are logged in on that website too.

Comment: @Scuzzy It depends on the situation, sometimes the nature in which this integration will be set up is on totally different servers, while other times it will be set up on the same domain and same server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF you wanna login through CURL that's easy, if you wanna send the cookie info in the headers of the request used in CURL that's easy too.

but if you want to login through CURL and use such cookies in the User's browser it's impossible . .